# Explaining how insertion sort works

Tags: java, sorting

I need to understanding the algorithm for insertion sort.

If someone can explain in layman terms how this code breaks down.

```
  public void insertionSort() {
      int in, out;
    for(out=1; out<nElems; out++) {
        long temp = a[out];
              in = out;
                 while(in>0 && a[in-1] >= temp){
                        a[in] = a[in-1]; // shift item right,
                                  --in;
                                    a[in] = temp; } // end for
```

I would like to know in particular why

1. What i do not understand is, in other sorts we use the for loop, and in this one we are using while loop in this particular sort?

2.a[in-1] >= temp, are they using this because we have removed one element?

Comment: i suggest to read up some basics of programming...once you have learned them...debugging the already available program will help

Comment: hmm Also the question doesn't seem to be Java-specific

Comment: Seriously? man, there are a lot material on the internet about this, I guess you haven't even searched it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to understand insertion sort algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392225/trying-to-understand-insertion-sort-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

> What i do not understand is, in other sorts we use the for loop, and
>   in this one we are using while loop in this particular sort?

Humm no. Some sort implementations don't even have a loop. In this particular case they use a `while` loop because the number of iterations is not known in advance, but in Java the `for` loop can do the exact same things as a `while` loop so it's just a matter of readability

> a[in-1] >= temp, are they using this because we have removed one
>   element ?

Because they perform a shift, which is always done by storing one of the shifted elements in a temporary variable. This is probably the most classical programming trick :

```
a = 5, b = 6
tmp = a
b = a
a = tmp
// now a is 6 and b is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. while loops and for loops are (essentially) equivalent, because you can always do:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   ```

   as

   ```
   int i = 0
   while (i < n) {
      ...
      i++;
   }
   ```

(The scope of `int i` is a little different e.g. in Java because in for loops its scope of `i` is only inside the the loop.)

2. It is not. The algorithm is trying to move the current value backwards in the array.
   I think the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Insertion_sort.gif) inside it is very helpful in understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on how a while loop is structured, it can serve the same purpose as for loop. Additionally, most sorts utilize recursion. My advice to you is

1) Look up insertion sort, basic enough but look at a visual representation and analyze what is being done. That'll help you understand what is going on in the code.

2) Think about the run time (which is O(n^2) average case). Why is it O(n^2)? What does this mean?